# Get Data for day-1,day-7,day-14,day-21 and day-28

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle.I wanted data for day-1,day-7,day-14,day-21 and day-28.
I have time_stamp column which has date for each day.

Comment: provide sample data

Comment: What do you mean by 'want data' ?

Answer (score 0):

you just subtract 1,7,14, etc. from [SYSDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm), example for one day:

```
select  <your columns>
from    <your table>
where   time_stamp < sysdate-1;
```

note that sysdate includes the current time of the day, so if you need from the prior whole day use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` to set the time components to 0.

[SYSDATE math](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/oracle-sysdate/)

Comment: I also have a similar scenario, I want to execute the query for every month that is query to fetch data from table ranging 1 to 6, 7 to 13, 14 to 20, 21 to the last day of the month. I can trigger it automatically on a particular day but am not able to write oracle logic.